# why the animation in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions failed?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I just want to diaplay the view with animation in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, my codes are like the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    CGRect finalRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"122.jpg"]; 

    UIButton* pic = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:finalRect];
    [pic setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pic setHidden:true];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(finalRect.size.width / 2, finalRect.size.height / 2);


    UIViewController* controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setView:pic];

    [self.window setRootViewController:controller];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.5];
    [pic setHidden:false];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;
}
```

but the animation does not work at all. The subview with a picture just showed in the screen suddenly. But if I use a button to trigger the animation codes, the view will appear with animation as supposed to. Is there any restricts on the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

PS:

This problem is resolved by moving the animation codes into the viewDidAppear proc of the controller just like rokjarc said below.

But there is another solution for this by execute the animation codes in a delayed routine called from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(executeAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button gets covered by `controller.view` which is also loaded in `window.view` on top of your `pic`.

You can solve this by moving the code to `controller::viewDidAppear`.

If you decide to go this way don't forget to add the button to `controller.view` instead of `appDelegate.window`.

Since it looks that you only want to show this animation at application launch you could set add a BOOL property called showAnimation to controller. Set this property to `YES` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and to `NO` at the end of `controller::viewDidAppear`.

This way you can conditionally (`if (self.showAnimation)...`) show the desired animation only once (in `controller::viewDidAppear`).

Comment: this is helpful! I put the animation codes in the viewDidAppear proc of the controller and it works. Thanks.